# Tablesorter plugin - how to save and restore scrollpos after postback?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, vertical-scrolling

Tablesorter is working wonderfully (thanks to Mottie for all the very useful updates) but I can't find a way to save the currently selected row and restore it after postback.

I'm using the 'scroller' and saveSort' widgets, which work just fine and the latter correctly restores the selected sort order, but I'm not managing to retrieve the current scrollPos (much less restore it afterwards) so the selected row is out of view if not within the default viewport. I must be missing something obvious or trying to overcomplicate this :). In the snippet below, which is after the tablesorter is initialised, the alert isn't triggered:

```
var thisGrid = $("#myGrid")
$(thisGrid).scrollParent().scroll(function () {
// $("#scrollPos").val($(thisGrid).scrollParent().scrollTop());
alert($(thisGrid).scrollParent().scrollTop());
});
$(thisGrid).scrollParent().scrollTop($("#scrollPos").val());
```

I've also tried at a .NET page level

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"
```

Thanks for any helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can work. The Page.MantaintScrollPositionOnPostback is an ASP.NET specifica feature while tablesorter is "server unaware".

I think the best solution for you is to avoid postbacks and replace them with partial posts (using Update Panels) or AJAX calls.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I appreciate that tablesorter is client-side but I have used this technique before with tables in a scrollable div and have been able to restore the current row. As TableSorter is able to remember the sort order, handling the current row would seem trivial :)

I don't think I can avoid the need to postback, as there is a lot that needs to happen at the server side and which all works fine, aside from keeping the current row in view.

Comment: Anyone else any suggestions, please? 

I can get the table scroller to record the scrollTop() value, but it won't scroll to that value on demand.

Comment: Further: It *does* seem to work in Chrome, but that's not the standard browser we have to support - IE9.